# Getting an error w/ this code. trying to make a lua script that rewards a player when they kill a player Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

Hrph. Anything wrong with the code below? Any improvements are welcomed

```
local function OnPlayerJoin(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new ("Folder")
    local currency1 = Instance.new ("IntValue")

    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    currency1.Name = "Gold"

    leaderstats.Parent = player
    currency1.Parent = leaderstats

    game.Players.CharacterAdded:connect(function(character)
        local Humanoid.Died:connect(function()
            if Humanoid:FindFirstChild("creator") ~=nil then
                local killer = Humanoid.creator.Value
                currency1 = currency1 + 5
            end
        end)
    end)

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(OnPlayerJoin)

end
```

Comment: The leaderstats script is further up but it wouldn't paste.

Comment: What actually is the error you are getting?

Comment: you're most likely getting an error for adding 5 to currency. but without the actual error message no one can help you... also creating local variables like killer that are not used doesn't make too much sense.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I could find on this script currently is this

`currency1 = currency1 + 5`

Where it should be

`currency1.Value = currency1.Value + 5`

As "currency1" is an object but it's value is a property, Also if this answer doesn't fix the problem please include a screenshot of the error you are getting and show us the Weapon script which kills the player.

Comment: Heyo, just a heads up, screenshots of errors and code are usually frowned upon. They should definitely include the error, but it should be in text. :)